# Openness of $S=\{(x, \sin(1/x) : x>0\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S=\{(x, \sin(1/x) : x>0\}$.

My understanding is that $S$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $S$ is open in the subspace topology.

Is it correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.  Do you understand why you are right?

Here is an intuitive idea of why you are right about $S$ not being open:

Think about the graph of $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ in the $xy$-plane for $x > 0$.  Now, pick some point on the curve, maybe at $x = 100$ (or anywhere).  Draw a ball around that point of any radius $\epsilon$.  Are only elements of that graph in the ball?  No, of course not.  You will always have pieces of "white space" (i.e., the complement of $S$) in the open ball around the point in $S$, and this is true for any ball you draw, of any radius.  So $S$ can't be open, since if it were open, then for each point in it, we can find a radius such that the ball around that point contains only points in $S$.

Now, as far as $S$ being open in the subspace topology, you have to specify which subspace you are talking about.  If you mean the subspace topology of $S$, then of course $S$ is open in its own subspace topology.  That's a trivial statement, like saying $\Bbb R$ is open in its own topology.  Intuitively, if you pick any point on $S$, then the "ball" in the subspace topology looks like an open interval, but it is an open interval *on the curve itself*.  Of course, any point on the curve has an open ball around it that contains only points in the curve (if we are working in the subspace topology).

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes more sense now!

Comment: @Sine_curve You're welcome!